# Chebyshev Polynomial - Properties for right solution

Tags: real-analysis

I have asked a few days ago about the same topic, but I think I have made some progress and I would be very grateful for any help and guidance.

The Chebyshev Polynomial $C_n$. I have to argue that $C_{n+1}$ can be written as:
$$C_{n+1}(t) = 2^n (t - \theta_{0,0})(t - \theta_{0,1})\dots(t - \theta_{0,n}),$$
where the parentheses can be written as $w^c_n(t)$ and $\theta_{0,k}, k = 0, 1,\dots,n $ are the $n + 1$ roots of $C_{n+1}$.

I have to show that $max_{t \in [-1,1]}$ for $| w^c_n(t) |$ = $ \frac{1}{2^n} $.

I'm lost. Don't know which properties of the Chebyshev Polynomials I have to use. Would be very grateful for any help.

Comment: No, you are dividing 0 by 2^n so that would be 0.

Comment: You have to use some properties of the Chebyshev polynomials because this is not true for all polynomials.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. What kind of properties are these? (and if you by chance know where can I read more?)

Comment: The Wikipedia article isn't much help, but you can try this: http://www.mhtl.uwaterloo.ca/courses/me755/web_chap6.pdf

Comment: I'm still lost. Which properties do I have to use?